# How do I rename a bunch of tables using a pattern?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a large group of database tables originally named with a prefix of "tblXYZ123-". I still want the tables to be prefixed as this keeps the related tables grouped together but I want to rename this group of tables by replacing the prefix with a simpler, more relevant prefix like "td".

How do I rename the tables without renaming each file manually? I'm hoping for a script or something but haven't been able to find such a tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build this script using dynamic SQL and the catalog view `sys.tables`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
  + 'EXEC sp_rename N''' + SCHEMA_NAME([schema_id])
  + '.' + name + ''', N''' + REPLACE(name, 'tblXYZ123-', 'td')
  + ''',N''OBJECT'';'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE 'tblXYZ123-%';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You could also use a cursor if you wanted, but I prefer the above - I can print and preview the script before I run it, for example:

```
DECLARE @t SYSNAME, @f NVARCHAR(511);

DECLARE c CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
  FOR SELECT name, SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name
    FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'tblXYZ123-%';

OPEN c;

FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @t, @f;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @t = REPLACE(@t, 'tblXYZ123-', 'td');

    EXEC sp_rename @f, @t, N'OBJECT';

    FETCH NEXT FROM c INTO @t, @f;
END 

CLOSE c;
DEALLOCATE c;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way, in my opinion, is to put the list of tables in a column in Excel.  In the next column, put in the new name, presumably with a formula like *="td"&mid(A1, 11, 1000)* for the new name.  In the third column, put in the formula "sp_rename "&A1&" "&A2.

Copy the formulas down, then copy the third column into SQL Server Management Studio and run the code.

You would also do this using a cursor or loop in T-SQL.  However, I find that generating such code in Excel -- for one time applications -- is usually the fastest way to go.

Comment: Personally I find the query I posted only a little more complex than the query you'd have to run to generate the list to copy to Excel. And it doesn't use any explicit loops or cursors.